# create a function that generate a list of numbers from a to b

Tags: haskell

I want to write a function that generates a list of all numbers between `a` and `b` expect those given in another list:

```
generate :: Int -> Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
```

#### Example

- input:  `generate 2 6 [10,3,5,8]`
- output: `[2,4,6]`

Comment: You can split the problem into two parts: first generate a list of numbers from `a` to `b`, and then given that list remove all the numbers that are also in `l`.

Comment: this is most likely some kind of homework so here a few hints: you can get the list itself with just `[a..b]` (given `a` and `b` are sensible) - then have a look at `delete` (http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:delete)

Comment: Would list comprehensions be acceptable in the solution? You could take a look at that too for this kind of problem I think.

Answer (score 1):

Even though this is most likely homework I think you can learn something if I give you the answer like this:

```
import Data.List (delete)

generate :: Int -> Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
generate a b = foldl (flip delete) [a..b]
```

Here is your example in ghci:

```
Prelude Data.List> generate 2 6 [10,3,5,8]
[2,4,6]
```

Now try to understand the parts and what is going on here - maybe ask some questions in the comments.

Comment: I cant understand what acually do the magic "flip delete" I know what delete do but dont know what they do together

Comment: ah right ... look at the definition/signature of `foldl` ...(hint: you don't need `flip` if you use `foldr` instead) - and of course `flip f a b = f b a` - it just *flips* around the *arguments*)

Comment: Thank you for the time and for the answer I was trying to do in other way , maybe I dont understand the core of the Haskell and functional programming and that makes the problem.

Comment: why don't you add what you tried to your question? There are more than one way to do a thing - don't let yourself get disencouraged. You have to unlearn this nasty imperative and object-oriented garbage first ;)

Comment: Probably should use `foldl'`, no reason to need that extra laziness as far as I can tell.

Comment: yes but then the next question would be "what is this ' ?" - and maybe it's better not go shave this yak at this moment

Comment: I learn Haskell from 5 days so... I am even not a beginner but a baby in that type of language , it's for my exam ,maybe after I pass it I would try to understand it more deeply but for now I have to pass it just to have the option to pass this year and to go forward with my education , but I find it very different from everything else and thats interesting , thank you all for the time you gave to my question

Comment: Np - in Haskell I feel like a beginner no matter how much I learn ;) - just ask if you don't get something - but maybe the Haskell IRC channel might be a better place